# Chrome 79 bug just wiped Local Storage from my Cordova app. Any way my users can restore?

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova

According to [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/12/15/google-pauses-chrome-79-rollout-on-android-after-bug-wipes-data-in-some-apps/) 15 Dec 2019, a chrome bug is wiping out local storage in Cordova apps, and I've had user reports confirming.

> One of the changes in Chrome 79 is that the location where web data is
>   stored was updated. However, as one comment on a Chromium bug page
>   pointed out, data from localStorage and WebSQL — two types of storage
>   commonly used by web apps and packaged apps — wasn't migrated
>   properly.
>
> Long story short, when devices were updated to Chrome 79, web apps and
>   WebView applications had some (or all) local data deleted. While the
>   data is still technically intact, since Chrome didn't delete old data
>   after the migration, there's no way to access it right now.

If the data is 'technically intact' is there a way for an end user to access and retrieve it? In my case, my cordova app stores key pairs of journal entries and related data, and if they can retrieve a plain text version of local storage the app has a means to restore from that.

I don't have a test device on which to replicate the problem, has anyone tried [this recovery process](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?utm_campaign=2016q3&utm_medium=redirect&utm_source=dcc) to try and access the local.storage files? It's a highly complex, long shot process for an end-user to go through, but I've got a few desperate users who just might slog through it. If someone has a recommendation for a simpler way, I'm all ears.

It's hard to believe the data is intact but "there is no way to access it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Google has removed chrome 79 from Play Store, so you can tell users to remove the Chrome update and install again, they'll get 78 and all their data will be in place.

Old answer:
The data is not lost, just stored in a different place, you can launch an update of your app with this code that copies the data from the old location to the new location.

https://gist.github.com/dpesch/a3fc3b7611068dd8b27bda9380ae07ac

It’s very big, so won’t copy everything, just the important part

```
private void _migrateUserDataToDefault() {
    String appPath = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;

    try {
        copyRecursive(new File(appPath, "/app_webview/databases/"), new File(appPath, "/app_webview/Default/databases/"));
        copyRecursive(new File(appPath, "/app_webview/Local Storage/"), new File(appPath, "/app_webview/Default/Local Storage/"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _renameOldData();

}
```